# Can I make something similar to a makefile for psql?

Tags: postgresql-9.3, psql

Basically I have a handful of .sql files that I regularly modify in structure that need to be run in a certain order:

```
CREATE.sql,
INSERT.sql,
PLPSGSQL.sql,
TEST.sql,
DROP.sql
```

Since every structural modification requires a full re-run of this sequence I would like to save myself the trouble of tapping throgh my command history and compile them into a makefile-esque structure; e.g.

```
$ Makepsql
$ psql
> \i CREATE.sql
> \i INSERT.sql
> \i PLPSGSQL.sql
> \i TEST.sql
> \i DROP.sql
> \q
```

Is there something like this?

Comment: Check out tools like Liquibase or Flyway.

Comment: Sadly I'm not working on my own environment, but on an university server.

Comment: So what? Liquibase is just a command line tool

Comment: You can include multiple files from a main one - and then just run this file using `psql -f main_file.sql`

Comment: I don't have any admin rights on that server, so I may not install any tools.. That's what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a bash script and pass those files as arguments to psql.

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e #abort on error

psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f CREATE.sql
#...insert your scripts here
#...
psql -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f DROP.sql
```

If you want the Makefile functionality (e.g. check modified dates of files and dependencies), just write a Makefile, and use the psql commands!